# java 1.6_45 client disable SSLv2Hello message

Tags: java, jsse

I am using a java client application which runs on jdk 1.6_45.

When the client initiates an HTTPS connection, it sends an `SSLv2Hello` message even though I have configured `-Dhttps.protocols=tlsv1` in java command line options.

**My question** is  how do I disable the `SSLv2Hello` message (sending from client as part of handshake) from java command line options?

Comment: How are you creating the HTTPS connection?  `-Dhttps.protocols` isn't universal and is ignored in some situations.

Comment: I am using Jetty as the client application (Jetty(7.6.7.v20120910))

Comment: Unless either Jetty or you use `HttpsURLConnection` to create the socket, `https.protocols` will have no effect. Jetty must have some other way of controlling this.